# Creating Index on Table in a schema

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2005, database-schema, indexing

I am logged in as 'sa', with full admin rights, and I am running the following command:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_EntityAuditId] ON [Maintenance.EntityAuditMessagesArchive] 
([EntityAuditId] ASC) ON [PRIMARY]
```

and getting the error:

> Cannot find the object "Maintenance.EntityAuditMessagesArchive" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.

The object does exist, because I can select from it. Furthermore, the command works if the table is not in a schema. i.e.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_EntityAuditId] ON [EntityAuditMessagesArchive] 
    ([EntityAuditId] ASC) ON [PRIMARY]
```

works (when I create the table without a schema, of course).

So, I can't create the index when the table is in the Maintenance schema. Why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a `.` in your name.  I'm guessing you need to change it to:

`[Maintenance].[EntityAuditMessagesArchive]`

A period inside the brackets indicates it is a part of the name, not a separator.

Comment: In other words - you're absolutely right. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @brundlefly - happy to help.  I've done this a few times myself, when you alter SSMS-generated scripts and put the brackets in the wrong spots (or insert stuff into the brackets SSMS generated).